# ZK Component with independent columns

Tags: components, zk

i am new to ZK framework[newbie] version 5.0.8 M.V.C approach i am trying to implement a component which their columns are independent from each other.... all i wanna to do is be able to represent the data on 2 columns and be able to respond to a click on each column

Something like

```
-----------------------------------
  Company----Company
   Oracle    IBM
   Microsoft Xerox
   HP        Apple
 -----------------------------------
```

if i click IBM i want not to click Oracle.....[in the same component i mean i dont want to create 2 grid or 2 listbox or else]

is this possible? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what exactly you need in terms of *independence* here. Are you looking for separation in terms of your data model or do you just want different event listeners for each rendered cell?

Regarding event listeners, it's very easy to attach listeners to anything you'd like. In ZK, the [HTMLBasedComponent](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Base_Components/HtmlBasedComponent#Supported_Events) is one of the common root components and support `onClick`, `onDoubleClick`, `onRightClick`, and more.

As these ZK components are being created dynamically, you can't [wire event listeners](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Event_Handling/Event_Listening#Composer_and_Event_Listener_Autowiring) with the `@Listen` annotation. The problem is that you don't have an id for the cells in advance.

Instead, you need to [programmatically create the `EventListener`](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Event_Handling/Event_Listening#Event_Listener) as you render.

```
// in your RowRenderer

public void render(Row row, Data data, int index) {
    Label column1 = new Label(data.getOne());
    Label column2 = new Label(data.getTwo());
    column1.setParent(row);
    column2.setParent(row);
    column1.addEventListener(Events.ON_CLICK, new EventListener<Event>() {
        public void onEvent(Event event) {
            // handle event
        }
    });
    column2.addEventListener(Events.ON_CLICK, new EventListener<Event>() {
        public void onEvent(Event event) {
            // handle event
        }
    });
}
```

Note that as implemented here, you create a new `EventListener` for every cell rendered. This is not very efficient so if you can make your `EventListener` stateless and attach the necessary data to the `Label` itself, you can save a lot of computation.

Regarding separation of code, if your data model is column oriented rather than by row, you won't find a standard ZK component that caters to this. That is to say, components like `Grid` and `Listbox` are rendered as rows starting at the top using `RowRenderers` and the like. If this is your problem, you'll want to roll your own component. This is a lot easier than it might sound.

```
public class ColumnGrid extends Hlayout {

    private ColumnListModel model;
    private ColumnRenderer<? extends Component> renderer;

    public void setModel(ColumnListModel model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public void setRenderer(ColumnRenderer renderer) {
        this.renderer = renderer;
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        for (int i=0; i<model.size(); i++) {
            Column col = new Column();
            appendChild(col);
            renderer.render(col, model.getElementAt(i), i);
        }
    }

}

public class Column extends Vlayout {}

public interface ColumnRenderer<T extends Component> {

    render(Column column, T data, int index);

}
```

It's just a skeleton, but you get the idea.

You can then even use this in your `zul` files:

```
<?component name="colGrid" class="com.sean.is.cool.ColumnGrid" ?>
<colGrid model="myModel" renderer="myColRenderer"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the table like `Components` of zk, alway a row is equal
to an object and a colum to an attribute of this object.
That means, `Listbox` and `Grid` will not help you.
If you use EE version of zk, I guess you may like to use [Choosenbox](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Input/Chosenbox).
Else I don't think there is `Component` for that.